# Вывести значение вместо кода

Tags: c#, winforms, access

Делаю самостоятельную работу по базам данных. Сказали, что вместо ключей должны выводится значения этих ключей. Теперь вопрос. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такая бд. Есть таблица Заказы и Запись. В таблице Заказы столбец Код записи связан со столбцом Код в таблице Записи. Что, по вашему мнению, нужно выводить в код записи ? Какое там значение вообще можно вывести, чтобы пользователю всё было понятно ?
P.S. Бд составлял учитель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из таблицы `Запись` брать особо ничего, кроме даты, но это явно не то, что нужно. Скорее всего, идти по коду песни и брать её название из таблицы `Архив песен`.
Пример SQL-запроса:

```
SELECT [Заказы].*, [Архив песен].[Название] FROM [Заказы]
JOIN [Запись] ON [Заказы].[Код записи] = [Запись].[Код]
JOIN [Архив песен] ON [Запись].[Код песни] = [Архив песен].[Код]
```

Comment: Средствами visual studio это можно сделать ?

Comment: @Андрей, Ну конечно, только SQL знать желательно для реализации таких вещей.

Comment: Просто я знаю как вывести значение со связанными таблицами, а как через таблицу - нет.

Comment: @Андрей, ну так тут тоже связь ничем не отличается, просто двойной JOIN будет.

Comment: Я пытался просто поменять тип столбца Код записи на comboBox и выводить туда из таблицы Архив песен Название песни. Но выводится ошибка, что недопустимое значение.

Comment: @Андрей, изучайте как составлять SQL запросы. Ответ я обновил, привел пример нужного вам запроса.

Comment: Ваш запрос выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса FROM

Comment: @Андрей, попробуйте таблицу после `FROM` без квадратных скобок указать.

Comment: Тоже самое выбивает.

Comment: @Андрей, Вы какую СУБД используете?

Comment: Microsoft Access

Comment: @Андрей, попробуйте убрать скобки везде, где встречаются имена таблиц в запросе. А вообще почитайте документацию по синтаксису sql на Access. Он просто, немного отличается от синтаксиса в MS SQL, а я привел пример именно на нем.